# Can I use aUITabBar and a UIToolBar at the same time?

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I have been searching for how to do this the past day or so. I have read comments that you shouldn't do this but when I look at other apps I see it. For an example look at the App Store app. It uses a TabBar at the bottom for navigation. Then at the top of the Featured and Top 25 section it has what appears to be a ToolBar allowing the user to be more specific about what content they wish to view. I would like to implement something similar, but can't figure out how they have done it. The phone app uses this as well.

Am I mistaken that the top bar is a ToolBar?

Any  insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a Segmented Control inside a Navigation Bar, a ToolBar is something entirely different.  There are plenty of tutorials online for customizing the innards of a Navigation Bar.

In fact you should just be able to drag one into your view's navigation bar within Interface Builder.  From there you can customize it's different segments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try doing it with a Navigation Bar. So to be clear, I can customize the navigation bar with the segmented controls and it won't act like the typical navigation bar which pushes and pulls views from a stack. Is this correct?

Comment: Well adding any type of UI elements to a navigation bar isn't going to change the functionality of a navigation controller.  It's still going to manage a stack of view controllers and push/pop/swap views all that fun stuff.  By putting items in the navigation bar it's just another means of distinguishing one view on the stack from another.  You very well could have accomplished the same task by putting the segmented control in the view itself.